# Why the same "for loop" method is not accepted by PHP, but in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

As a beginner I know how to work with basic for and foreach loops in PHP. Most of the time we prefer foreach for arrays. I am asking this just for the sake of insight into this "for loop" behavior and how it varies compared with javascript. The same loop in Javascript gives us results. 
(Experts feel the question is insane pls don't downvote it)

**Javascript**

```
var arrayList = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"];
var text = "";
for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) 
{
   text += arrayList[i] + "<br>";   
}
 document.write(text);
```

**PHP**-I know it will work if I put the variable in the loop, but why not in PHP

```
$_array = array("PHP", "Javascript", "C++", "Jquery", "Python");
$total = count($_array);
$result = "";
for($i = 0; $ i <$total; $i++)
{
 $result += $_array[$i]."<br>";
 }
echo $result;
```

Comment: this extra space `$ i` is just a typo here, right?

Comment: In PHP, strings are added (as you show) using `.` rather than `+`.  This also applies to `+=` should be `.=` for PHP.

Comment: They are completely different languages, so why would they have to work the same way?

Comment: That not at all problem. I just type here like that. When u correct and test that, it gives 0

Comment: adding to Nigels answer: when using the + operator php will try to get the intval of the string. If you put "5php" and "4Javascript" in the array the result will be 9

Comment: Javascript and PHP have different concatenation operator. JS uses "+" but PHP uses "."

Comment: @Andreas But this is a basic loop. Is it wrong for the beginner expect to go everything right when he starts? That's my doubt.That's it

Comment: It's like asking "Why do I have to move my feeds differently when riding a bike or a car. They both bring me from A to B.". The question doesn't make much sense as they are two completely different "things" as are JavaScript and PHP. They will both have a way to iterate over a collection but they don't have to work the exact same way.

Comment: @Andreas , Qirel and everyone What confused me in javascript is I thought it was a increment operator (+). That's why I tried it in PHP. And now I know "+" used in the meaning of concatenation, not as increment. Thank you. Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP concatenation operator is DOT ("."), not PLUS ("+") character:

**WRONG**

```
$result += $_array[$i]."<br>";
```

**RIGHT**

```
$result .= $_array[$i]."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few corrections here:

```
<?php /* missing */
$_array = array("PHP", "Javascript", "C++", "Jquery", "Python");
$total = count($_array);
$result = "";
for($i = 0; $i <$total; $i++) /* remove extra space between $<space>i */
{
 $result .= $_array[$i]."<br>"; /* replace + with . */
}
echo $result;
```

BTW, php has `implode()` which does the same:

```
<?php
$result = implode("<br/>",array("PHP", "Javascript", "C++", "Jquery", "Python"));
echo $result;
```

Equivalent short code for JS:

```
var text = ["php", "javascript", "c++", "C lang", "Python"].join("<br>");
document.write(text);
```